# Ansible Alternative directory structure requires paths

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-role

I am trying to create the **Alternative Directory Layout** from the Ansible docs [site](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) best practices section.

Following this guidance, here is the layout that I have created inside `~/ansible_proj/windows_setup` (`windows_setup` is a Python virtual environment):

```
.venv
inventories/
   production/
      hosts
      group_vars/
         windows
            windows.yml
            vault

windows_configure.yml

roles/
    role1/
    role2/
    role3/
    role4/

.gitignore # this contains 1 line produced by: echo 'vault' >> .gitignore
```

When I try to run the playbook `windows_configure.yml`, as suggested [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#what-this-organization-enables-examples) (see 1st example), using

```
$ (.venv) cd ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup
$ (.venv) user@sname: ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup$ ansible-playbook
                      -i production windows_configure.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

the error is

```
Unable to parse /.../production as an inventory source

production hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

I must indicate the path to the `hosts` file instead like:

```
$ (.venv) user@sname: ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup$ ansible-playbook
                       -i inventories/production/hosts windows_configure.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

in order for this to run.

**Q1.** How can I use the **Alternative Directory Layout** to run playbooks by using `production` (as the docs suggest) instead of `inventories/production/hosts`?

---

In the same directory structure, if I place `windows_configure.yml` inside `playbooks/`, and run with:

```
$ (.venv) user@sname: ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup$ ansible-playbook
                      -i inventories/production/hosts playbooks/windows_configure.yml
                      --ask-vault-pass
```

then I get this error

```
ERROR: the role 'role1' was not found in /.../playbooks/roles:/.../playbooks
```

**Q2.** In this Alternative Directory Structure, is it possible to place all playbooks inside a `playbooks` directory?

---

**EDIT**

I have tried [adding `ansible.cfg` to the current directory](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11175#issuecomment-189560147) (`~/ansible_proj/windows_setup`) (which also contains the playbook `windows_configure.yml`. Here is `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
inventory  = ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup/inventories/production
roles_path = ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup
```

When I run

```
$ (.venv) cd ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup
$ (.venv) user@sname: ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup$ ansible-playbook
                      -i production windows_configure.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

the same error appears

```
Unable to parse /.../production as an inventory source

production hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Q1.** only:

It appears this question is discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18686#issuecomment-263949605) - the solution is to use `inventories/production`. I tested this (without any `ansible.cfg` file in the current directory) and it worked:

```
$ (.venv) user@sname: ~/ansible_proj/windows_setup$ ansible-playbook
                      -i inventories/production windows_configure.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

For **Q2.**:

It looks like symbolic links might be one approach - I didn't want to do this so I left the playbook in the root project directory and not within a `playbooks` directory. However, some symbolic link based solutions are here: [1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12862#issuecomment-311993510), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40693370/4057186). I'm not sure if there is another way to resolve this problem.